# SQL alter column and drop constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to alter a column constrain while also changing its size  - tried doing it like this

```
ALTER TABLE public.school
ALTER COLUMN  class_name TYPE  text
DROP CONSTRAINT class_name;
```

but for some reason am I getting an syntax error near DROP

the only way I can execute this is by

```
ALTER TABLE public.school
ALTER COLUMN  class_name TYPE  text

ALTER TABLE public.school
DROP CONSTRAINT class_name;
```

Somehow possible to combine into one query and not two?

Comment: You need a comma after `text` or a separate `alter table` statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  thanks :)